# Как отследить все запущенные таймеры на странице?

Tags: javascript

Установил почтовый клиент rainlooop

js раз в определенное количество времени шлет запрос на php скрипт, который уже связывается c моим аккаунтом и получается список писем.
Хочу изменить интервал проверки писем. если увидеть отправляемые запросы из консоли я могу то вот как увидеть какие таймеры стоят и в каких функциях, не понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант переопределить стандартный setInterval в самом начале загрузки страницы и собрать все таймеры, соответствующие функции и интервалы в массив объектов.
После полной загрузки страницы у вас будет массив объектов с полной информацией от таймерах. Затем у вас появится отличная возможность управлять таймерами так как вам необходимо `"динамически"`!

### Пример реализации:

```js
window.originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;
let activeTimers = [];

//Переопределение стандартного setInterval
window.setInterval = function(callback, interval) {
  const handler = window.originalSetInterval(callback, interval);
  activeTimers.push({
    handler: handler,
    callback: callback,
    interval: interval
  });
  return handler;
};

window.getActiveTimers = () => {
  return activeTimers.slice();
};

setInterval(() => {
  console.log('#1')
}, 5000);
console.log(getActiveTimers());
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('#2')
}, 5000);
console.log(getActiveTimers());

//Ждем полной загрузки всех ресурсов
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  //Сбрасываем переоределение стандартного setInterval
  window.setInterval = window.originalSetInterval;
  console.log('Все ресурсы загружены!');
  //Удалить все таймеры (setInterval) по "ID"
  activeTimers.map(elem => clearInterval(elem.handler));
  console.log('Все таймеры удалены!');
  //Но массив объектов у нас все еще есть
  console.log(getActiveTimers());

  //Инициализируем таймеры снова но уже из массив объектов 
  activeTimers.map(elem => setInterval(elem.callback, elem.interval));


  //То есть вы можете управлять таймерами динамически
  //Допустим я знаю что 2 таймер обновляется слишком быстро 5000мс
  //А мне надо больше 10000мс (или меньше)
  activeTimers.map(elem => {
    if (elem.handler == 2) {
      console.log('Второй таймер обновлен:');
      clearInterval(elem.handler);
      elem.interval = 10000;
      setInterval(elem.callback, elem.interval);
    }
  });
  console.log(getActiveTimers());
}, false);
```

Если есть вопросы могу дополнить ответ.

Comment: Ты просто икона для меня, не понимаю как так можно шарить...

Comment: только вот не знаю как приостановить загрузку скриптов, вставить свой в консоль а потом снова продолжить выполнение))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов этот скрипт надо загружать первым. не знаю как у вас js файлы устроены, вынесите этот скрипт в отдельный файл и загружайте его первым. и посмотрите что будет

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов помогло все таки или нет?)

Comment: Да успел сам файл разобрать и найти все связи. но буду использовать

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов +

Answer (score 3):

```js
var oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.setInterval = function(){
  var f = arguments[0];
  arguments[0] = function() {
    console.log("my interval wrapper:", f.toString(), JSON.stringify(arguments));
    f.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  oldSetInterval.apply(this, arguments);
};

setInterval(function(a, b){ 
  console.log("real interval", a + b) 
}, 1000, 23, 100);
```

Отследить уже запущенные интервалы - нельзя. Но если вставить/выполнить этот код до всех других скриптов на странице, все интервалы будут вызываться через эту обертку. Думаю, это можно сделать через js расширение для браузера.

Comment: На загруженной странице вставил ваш код в консоль. Начали выводиться интервалы которые созднаы в этом коде. Но как отследить все работающие, не понял, вообще возможно ли это. Если я не знаю их названий